# How to add new object into Array using AutoForm?

Tags: meteor-autoform

I have simple schema looking like:

```
Schema = new SimpleSchema
  name:
    label: "Order title"
    type: String
    optional: true

  offers:
    type: Array
    optional: true
  'offers.$':
    type: Object
  'offers.$.name':
    type: String
    min: 3
  'offers.$.selected':
    type: Boolean
    defaultValue: false
```

Firs I'm inserting new entry into Mongo collection. The, when I already have it, I want to add one more offer into it.

I have tried this code to add new offer into offers array, but it doesn't sent any data into method

```
+autoForm id="addOffer" schema=Schema type="method" meteormethod="addOffer" doc=data
  +afQuickField name='offers.$'
  button(type="submit") Add
```

It seems, that I can only edit all of them at once. E.g. using:

```
+autoForm id="updateOffer" collection="Order" type="update" doc=data
  +afQuickField name='offers'
```

Should I move offers into separate collection if I want to use autoForm to adding new one without seeing already added offers?

Comment: Give a shot and find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that *aldeed* just solved the problem in new AutoForm (5.0) release. Now we have `update-pushArray` form type.

More info here: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#update-pusharray

Comment: Is there a full example of this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Using `arrayTracker.addOneToField` should do the work. Take a look at this event handler here : https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/master/autoform-events.js#L474